# Panic Report: Zone cache element was used after free!

Tags: kernel-panic

Can anyone explain what caused this. Happened twice, consecutively.
Panic Report: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue on two separate Mac's (including a brand new 16" MacBook Pro I bought two days ago) both running Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76). It's happened on system wake, using Chrome, and randomly with no apps running in the foreground.

Perhaps a background process is responsible. What background processes are active? (I'm running the latest versions of Little Snitch, Intego Virusbarrier X9 and Creative Cloud).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).